# Relationship between fundamental matrix and exponential of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, matrix-equations

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. I need to show that if $\Phi$ is a fundamental matrix of the system $$Y^{\prime}=AY $$
then there exists an invertible matrix B such that $\Phi = e^{At}B$, where $e^{At}$ is the exponential of the matrix $A$.

I started out supposing I have $n$ linearly independent solutions $Y_{1},Y_{2},\cdots , Y_{n}$ to the system $Y^{\prime}=AY$. Then, $\Phi$ a fundamental matrix implies that $$\Phi = \begin{pmatrix} Y_{1} & Y_{2} & \cdots & Y_{n} \end{pmatrix}$$

But, I don't know where to go from here.

Could somebody please help me with this proof?

Thank you ahead of time for your time and patience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since

$\Phi = (Y_1 \; Y_2 \; \cdots \; Y_n), \tag 1$

that is, the columns of $\Phi$ are $n$ linearly independent solutions of

$Y' = AY, \tag 2$

we have

$\Phi' = (Y_1' \; Y_2' \; \cdots \; Y_n') = (AY_1 \; AY_2 \; \cdots \; AY_n) = A\Phi, \tag 3$

or

$\Phi' - A\Phi = 0; \tag 4$

now consider the matrix

$e^{-At} \Phi; \tag 5$

we have

$(e^{-At} \Phi)' = e^{-At} \Phi' - Ae^{-At} \Phi = e^{-At} \Phi' - e^{-At} A\Phi =  e^{-At}(\Phi' - A \Phi) = 0; \tag 6$

it follows that $e^{-At}\Phi$ is a constant matrix $B$:

$ e^{-At} \Phi = B; \tag 7$

this may be written

$\Phi = e^{At}B; \tag 8$

note that both $e^{-At}$ and $\Phi$ are invertible; the inverse of $e^{-At}$ is $e^{At}$:

$e^{At}e^{-At} = e^{At - At} = e^0 = I, \tag 9$

and $\Phi$ is invertible since it's columns are linearly independent.  So $B$ is invertible as well.  And we are done.

***Note:*** If follows from (7) that in fact

$B = \Phi(0) = (Y_1(0) \; Y_2(0) \; \cdots \; Y_n(0)). \tag{10}$